# prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i \, \partial x_j}(tx)x_ix_j$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function of class $C^2$, such that $f(tx)=t^2f(x)$ for every $t>0$ and every $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that if we derive the equality above twice with respect to $t$, we get that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\, \partial x_j}(tx)x_ix_j$.

I can't get this result, because

\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial f(tx)}{\partial t}=2t f(x)+t^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \\[8pt]
\Rightarrow {} & \frac{\partial^2 f(tx)}{\partial t^2}=2f(x)+2t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+2t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+t^2 \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial t^2} \\[8pt]
\Rightarrow {} & f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f(tx)}{\partial t^2}-2t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}-\frac{1}{2}t^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}.
\end{align}

Please, give-me a hint.

Comment: Your computation of the partial with respect to $t$ is  incorrect. I think you need to review things like the chain rule carefully. (In particular, what on earth does $\partial f / \partial t$ on the right hand side of the first equality even mean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an analogous question, with one fewer derivatives, and with only a single variable:

Show that if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies
$$
f(tx) = t f(x)
$$
for all $ t > 0$ and all $x$, then 
$$
f(x) = x f'(x).
$$

Do your best to do this problem without saying "The hypothesis tells me that $f$ is linear, so it's trivial!"

**POST-COMMENT ADDITION:**
Here's a solution: Fix $x$ and let 
$$
g(t) = f(tx).
$$
Then 
$$
g'(t) = f'(tx) x,
$$
by the chain rule. On the other hand, we also know, from the hypotheses, that

$$
g(t) = tf(x),
$$
so
$$
g'(t) = f(x).
$$
Setting these two expressions for $g'$ equal, and evaluating at $t = 1$, we get
$$
f(x) = f'(tx) x = f'(x) x.
$$
It may seem odd that $t$ is irrelevant here, but that's because $f'$ is a constant. But the proof I've given doesn't rely on that -- it's just a side remark.

**END ADDITION**

And then a version with multiple variables:

Show that if $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ satisfies
$$
f(tx, ty) = t f(x, y)
$$
for all $ t > 0$ and all $x, y$, then 
$$
f(x, y) = x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y) + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x, y).
$$

When you can do those two, you'll be easily able to do the problem you're working on.

Comment: Hello, John! Thank you for writing! For me the difficulty is the same, because $\frac{\partial f(tx)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f(tx)}{\partial (tx)}\frac{\partial (tx)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f(tx)x}{\partial (tx)}=t\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial t}+f(x)$. Happy New Year to you!

Comment: I've worked out the one-variable case very carefully for you. (See "Post Comment Additions"). I suggest that you try to do the 2-variable case equally carefully.